# hamming distance function

Tags: assembly, x86-64, hamming-distance

I've got this Java code:

```
long[] va = new long[] {1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
long[] vb = new long[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1};

long hamming(long[] va, long[] vb, long length) {
long hd = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
if (va[i] != vb[i]) {
hd++;
}
}
return hd;
}
```

and I'm trying to convert it to Assembly x86_64:

```
va: .quad 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
vb: .quad 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
length: .quad 5

ea rbx, va /*va to rbx */
lea rcx, vb /*vb to rcx */
xor rax, rax 
mov r8, [rbx] 
mov r9, [rcx] 
mov r10, length /* i = 5 */
cycle: 
    cmp r8, r9 /
    jne next 
    inc rax /* if r8 is not equal to r9 */
    next: 
    inc rbx /* moving the pointer in va */
    inc rcx /* moving the pointer in vb*/
    dec r10 /*i-- */
    jne cycle /* if i is not equal jump back to cycle */
    call print_rax
call print_all
```

The problem is that I can't run the assembly code. Can anybody tell me what's wrong? I'm completely new at assembly and I can't found out where the problem is.

Comment: Clarify “can’t run” and improve the title as relevant.

Comment: Your assembly code is not following the C code.  If you have a working algorithm in C, then don't make changes to the algorithm when you're translating to assembly.  Translate the C code literally and then the bugs will be assembly typos and translation errors instead of algorithm problems.  If you want to optimize, do it in C, then translate that.  Making algorithmic optimizations as you're translating to assembly, is a bad idea when you're just learning assembly.

Comment: Also, what does debugging this tell you?  You should be able to spot the error quite quickly by single stepping.